# Force Kubernetes Pod shutdown before starting a new one in case of disruption

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to set up a stateful Apache Flink application in Kubernetes and I need to save the current state in case of a disruption, such as someone deleting the pod or it being rescheduled due to cluster resizing.

I added a preStop hook to the container that accomplishes this behaviour, but when I delete a pod using `kubectl delete pod` it spins up a new Pod before the old one terminates.

Guides such as [this one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/) use the Recreate update strategy to make sure only one pod runs at a time. This works fine in case of updating a deployment, but it does not cover disruptions like I described above. I also tried to set `spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge` to 0 but that made no difference.

Is it possible to configure my Deployment in such a way that no pod *ever* starts before another one is terminated, or do I need to switch to StatefulSets?

Comment: I would switch to StatefulSets. Your proposed usecase is one of those they solve very well.

Comment: @Sander, What kind of current state do you want to save in case of a disruption?

Comment: @mk_sta Apache Flink is able to create save points from which it can continue, but that process should obviously complete before another pod starts

Comment: How did you share save points between Pods in cluster?

Comment: They are written to GCS, why?

Comment: I was wondering how did you configure you storage via Persistent Volume shared within a Pods.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Cosmic Ossifrage as [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/) make it easy to achieve your goal. Each Pod in `StatefulSets` is represented with unique, persistent identities and stable hostnames that Kubernetes Engine maintains regardless of where they are scheduled.

Therefore, `StatefulSets` are deployed in sequential order and are terminated in reverse ordinal order assuming that Kubernetes StatefulSet controller removes one Pod each time after complete deletion of previous one as well.